# Filter for Axis Y on MotionEvent object

Tags: android, touch-event, motionevent

Is there a way to create a new object from a MotionEvent object that extract only the X axis movement (gesture) ?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
MotionEvent xMotionEvent = filterYMotion(event);
return super.onTouchEvent(xMotionEvent);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: if you want to "zero" y values use transform()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setScale(1, 0);
        event.transform(matrix);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code to only extract the x value:

```
event.getX();
```

Comment: I need a MotionEvent object as result not only the X value